# Getting errors when moving D7/CiviCRM install form localhost xampp portable to another location

Tags: export

I have xampp portable installed on Windows 10.

I run about a dozen Drupal, Wordpress and other CMS on there. I can move the whole stack to different drives and machines and it all works perfectly, only one that can't work is D7/CIVICrm install.

When I move it to another directory I get this error:

```
fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CRM_Core_ClassLoader in C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\ClassLoader.php on line 36
```

Any idea how to make this work?

The files are absolutely identical from source to location, copy and paste whole Xampp portable folder...

Comment: Try install a fresh copy first and then try to restore the backup of CiviCRM Database that should work

Comment: That's what I'm doing, now working

Comment: Have you tried - https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/cannot-redeclare-class-crm-core-classloader-in-backup-site ?

Comment: Nope , NONE of that works, I think I might just drop CIVI CRM, I need a portable solution, been a week now...;(

Comment: Ok, I see something wrong here...the path of the error is C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\ but the new destination path is: G:\XAMPP_2018\htdocs  , so where can I change that setting? I take some kind of settings.php , config file or in the database with PHPmy admin?

Comment: you should see civicrm_setting file in sites/default/ if you need more help please let me know

Comment: I did a find and replace, I couldn't find any instances of C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\  in any files in destination folder, only log files, I'm at a loss!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82217/discussion-between-artech-consultancy-and-bruno-vincent).

Answer (score 1):

Had to change the path name in civicrm.settings.php from:

```
G:\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4
```

To

```
C:\Core\XAMPP_2018\htdocs\crm4\
```

This is around LINE 180:

Code looks like this:

$civicrm_root = 'G:/August25/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4/sites/all/modules/civicrm';
if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', 'G:/August25/XAMPP_2018/htdocs/crm4\sites\default\files\civicrm\templates_c\');
}

But the slashes also have to be forward like this "/", I searched from Windows path, that's why I couldn't find the code using find and replace!